How do I intercept non-navigation HTTP requests in Playwright?
In the following code (which uses Playwright), only the last HTTP request is intercepted:
import {test} from "@playwright/test";

test('experimental test', async ({ page, context }) => {
    await context.route('**/*', (route) => {
        console.log('Intercepted:', route.request().url());
        route.continue();
    });

    await fetch('https://example.com');
    await context.request.get('https://example.com');
    await context.request.fetch('https://example.com');
    await page.request.get('https://example.com');
    await page.goto('https://example.com'); // Only this one gets intercepted
});

I need to send some other request to the server, outside of regular navigation, but these need to be intercepted. How can I do this?
Further information, as requested
The above is a simplified proof-of-concept. The purpose of intercepting all calls from a test is as follows: I wish each test to be able to run on it's own database instance with a set of seeding data. This can be done by sending a setup call with a unique test ID to the backend, with each subsequent call also sending that ID. It would be helpful if all requests, including the setup calls (which are the ones that rely on a fetch, or similar) could be caught so that the Test ID could be added. For example:
base.beforeEach(async ({context}, testInfo) => {
    await context.route('**/*', async route => {
        const headers = route.request().headers();
        headers['Playwright-Test-Id'] = testInfo.project.name + '-' + testInfo.titlePath.join('-');
        await route.continue({ headers });
    });
})

So I was hoping there would be a way to send a request in the context of the page under test so that this ID could be set universally.

context.request is for API testing, route() only catches calls from the page under test. If you change to https://playwright.com you will see a bunch of console logs for images, assets and scripts.

I note that page.request (along with page.route()) didn't work either. Is there any way to intercept these other calls? Or make http calls in the context of the page under test so that they may be intercepted?

Any request from the test (page/context/fetch) are not captured by an intercept - there is no need, since the test is originating them. You just await the response and assert something about it - ref API testing.

This is unclear--as Achtung mentioned, there's no need to intercept requests you're sending from Node. You already have the requests and responses fully under your control. Please explain what you're trying to do.

I have added more information, as requested.

Now it's a different question. For db seeding, just create a wrapper function to add the header. The app itself will not know what to do with the header, so the route() is superfluous.

Assuming "non-navigation" means via API directly and not through UI, it seems like you're looking for writing API tests.
Here are Playwright Docs examples for API tests:
const REPO = "test-repo-1";
const USER = "github-username";

test("should create a bug report", async ({ request }) => {
  // POST Request
  const newIssue = await request.post(`/repos/${USER}/${REPO}/issues`, {
    data: {
      title: "[Bug] report 1",
      body: "Bug description",
    },
  });
  expect(newIssue.ok()).toBeTruthy();

  // GET Request
  const issues = await request.get(`/repos/${USER}/${REPO}/issues`);
  expect(issues.ok()).toBeTruthy();
});

Note that for API tests you should use request built-in fixture,
not context fixture that represents a web browser context (browser-window)
